# Django image (media) path don't display correctly in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, imagefield

In my project i had set my media folder like this:

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

then in my models.py i create a class like this one:

```
class PD_Pictures(models.Model):
    pic_IDmod = models.ForeignKey(PD_Models, related_name='modello')
    pic_image = models.ImageField()
    pic_descr = models.CharField(max_length=50)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.pic_descr
```

at this point in my function in `views.py` I extract all values in db related to `PD_Picture`:

```
prod_img = PD_Pictures.objects.all()
.....
return render(
    request,
    'base_catalog.html',
    {
        'bike_mod': bike_models,
        'prod_img': prod_img,
        'cat_list': cat_list,
        'menu_list': menu_list['menu'],
        'pcontent': menu_list['cont'],
        'form': c_form
    },
    context
)
```

and in my template, i would ti display related images:

```
{% for pic in prod_img %}
    <div class="4u">
        <span class="image fit"
            <img src="{{ pic.pic_image }}" alt="" />
        </span>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Well, at this point when I insert a new image in db, in table the path is `newimage.jpg`, physically on my server the image was stored in `/media/newimage.jpg`, how can I extract the value from the table and concatenate to the media path in my template? (`<server>/media/newimage.jpg`)

I have tried to use `upload_to='/models/'` in my `ImageField` but the only effect is to save image into another model folder into main model.

Comment: `pic.pic_image.url` will be the media url

Answer (score 2):

just try like this

`{% for pic in prod_img %}
     <img src="{{ pic.pic_image.url }}" alt="" />
{% endfor %}`

Comment: Some words or comment as to why this solves the issue would make it a nicer answer

Comment: because {% pic.pic_image.url %}  will return url of image and `src` attribute need url of image

Comment: hi, pic.pic_image and pic.pic_image.url return the same path 'pic1.jpg' instead of media/pic1.jpg

Comment: This should work if your on the dev server (ie using python manage.py runserver). If you're running it on a live server you will need to check your setup to correctly serve static files - this isn't handled by django, but by the webserver you have installed

Comment: or you can try   changed your urls `from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Answer (score 1):

From django official doc:

> FieldFile.url
>   A read-only property to access the file’s relative URL by calling the url() method of the underlying Storage class.

if you try to print in your template {{ pic.pic_image }} you'll receive the db field value, while with {{ pic.pic_image.url }} the url() method from django.core.files.storage.Storage will call, and your base settings 
would seem to be correct

Answer (score 0):

Can you make this into your template and see what path is given?

```
{% for pic in prod_img %}
  <p>{{ pic.pic_image }</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi , it return 'pin1.jpg' but phisically is in 127.0.0.1:8000/media/pic1.jpg